# How I can write mockito junit for Listener class

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, mockito

Hi how to write mockitJunit.

Please help how to write mockito junit for above class

Comment: Googling around for "mockito spring" (since this seems to be what you are using) would be a great place to start; if you come and ask a question without showing minimal effort, don't be surprised if your question gets closed.

Comment: As @fge said, go and do some research instead of just asking for a solution without even googling around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked.  Just add the checks for the system properties you set.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AppStartUpContextListenerTest {

    public AppStartUpContextListenerTest() {
    }

    @Mock
    ServletContextEvent mockEvent;
    @Mock
    ServletContext mockServletContext;
    @Mock
    Configuration mockConfig;
    @Mock
    WebApplicationContext mockWebContext;

    /**
     * Test of contextInitialized method, of class AppStartUpContextListener.
     */
    @Test
    public void testContextInitialized() {
        System.out.println("testContextInitialized");

        when(mockEvent.getServletContext()).thenReturn(mockServletContext);

        when(mockServletContext.getAttribute(Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(mockWebContext);

        AppStartUpContextListener instance = new AppStartUpContextListener();
        instance.contextInitialized(mockEvent);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.

        verify(mockEvent, times(1)).getServletContext();

    }

}
```